# Does "this" keyword return the DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a task where I need to move  elements with classname **clearOnHover** on click to another "div" element with classname **sortingContainer**. For that I wrote the following code.

```
$("body").on('click','.clearOnHover',function(){            
      $('.sortingContainer').append(this);              
});
```

"this" variable **removed** the  tags with classname "clearOnHover" from its original place in DOM and appended it to "sortingConatiner" div.

Can you help me understand why the element was removed from the DOM, and what exactly caused it.?

http://jsfiddle.net/NMWwL/1/

Comment: There is an article on removing, cloning and moving elements with jquery: http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/ - might be useful. And yes, jQuerys append can do exactly that, moving an element from one container to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append()` will always remove the DOM element from it's original position. If you need to copy it, use [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) instead.

From the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/) :

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)